# How can $a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle$ act on $x|00\rangle + y|11\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, hilbert-space, notation

How can the projective measurement $|A\rangle = a |0 \rangle + b |1 \rangle$ act on the two-qubit quantum state $|\Psi\rangle=x|00\rangle + y|11\rangle$?

edit:
Say A measures the first qubit of the two-qubit state. What's the probability of outcome 1?

See equation (6) [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.5634) for more context.

Comment: As written your $A$ is not a projective measurement but just a state.  Writing $\vert A\rangle = a\vert 0\rangle + b\vert 1\rangle$ you probably mean that $\vert A\rangle\langle A\vert$ is the projective measurement.  Then it can certainly act on your state by (presumably) projecting on the first component of $\vert ab\rangle$.

Comment: I have been following a set of notes in terms of notation, apologies if it's sloppy. When you write $|A\rangle\langle A|$ should it not be $|A^{*}\rangle\langle A|$? How exactly does this act on a state like $|00\rangle$? In other words, how do you define $\langle0|00\rangle$?

Comment: No it should not be $\vert A^*\rangle \langle A\vert$.  A projector is of the form $\vert a\rangle\langle a\vert $ much like $\hat x \hat x\cdot$ is a projector in the sense that $\hat x\hat x\cdot \vec r=\hat x r_x$ projects $\vec r$ along $\hat x$.  As to the second part of the question, that's the crux of it.  How do *you* define $\langle a\vert b c\rangle$?  Is it $\delta_{ab}\vert c\rangle$ or $\delta_{ac}\vert b\rangle$?  Your question cannot be answered until *you* know what you're projecting on (v.g. first or second factor).

Comment: I wish I could tell, but the paper I'm looking at doesn't say. The context is the CHSH test, with a 2-qubit state of the form given above and Alice performing measurements $|A_0\rangle =  a|0\rangle + b|0\rangle$, $|A_1\rangle = c|0\rangle + b|0\rangle$. I'm not sure if this is helpful?

Comment: Hmmm... it's probably clearer from context but as stated $\vert A_0$ is just not a measurement, unless it's implied that what is meant is $\vert A_0\rangle\langle A_0\vert$.  You can try projecting on the first or second entry and see which one gets you to where you want to go, but it seems the paper makes some implicit assumptions that are not immediately helpful to you.

Comment: But does it ultimately matter that this a two-qubit system given that it's a superposition of $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$? I mean it shouldn't matter which coordinate is being projected on?

Comment: Your added questions are also confusing. What do you mean by "the probability of outcome 1"? Who is doing the measurement, and on what basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two steps to this

- The first thing is to always act linearly with the bra:
  \begin{align}
  \langle A |\Psi\rangle 
  & =
  \langle A|\bigg[ x|00\rangle + y |11\rangle \bigg]
  \\ & =
  x\langle A|00\rangle + y \langle A|11\rangle
  \end{align}
- The second part is to understand how a single-party projector works on a bipartite tensor-product state. This requires either clearer notation or an explicit indication of what tensor factor the bra acts on; in this case, you've specified that it works on the first factor, so you have in general
  $$
  \langle A| uv\rangle 
  = \langle A| \cdot \left(|u\rangle \otimes |v\rangle \right)
  = \langle A|u\rangle \cdot |v\rangle,
  $$
  leaving you with a complex number, $\langle A|u\rangle$, multiplying a Bob-side state vector $|v\rangle$.

Putting the two together, you get the final result
\begin{align}
\langle A |\Psi\rangle 
& =
\langle A|\bigg[ x|00\rangle + y |11\rangle \bigg]
\\ & =
x\langle A|00\rangle + y \langle A|11\rangle
\\ & =
x\langle A|0\rangle |0\rangle + y \langle A|1\rangle |1\rangle
\\ & =
a^* x |0\rangle + b^* y |1\rangle,
\end{align}
i.e. a Bob-side state vector as above.

---

If you want to find out the probability of this outcome, you need to be slightly more specific, because you might be asking in correlation with a Bob-side measurement or not, and the correlated probabilities are different beasts, for starters because they depend on two independent variables instead of just one.

If you want to ignore whatever happens on Bob's side, that's also just fine, but even then it still pays off to build a complete picture of the projective measurement you're building, which would normally be on the basis
\begin{align}
|A\rangle & = \phantom{+} a |0 \rangle + b |1 \rangle,\\
|A^\perp\rangle & = -b^* |0 \rangle + a^* |1 \rangle.
\end{align}
(Two things to keep in mind: (i) the two-outcome measurement along a basis is not the most general projective measurement you can do; by coupling to an ancilla system you can implement a [POVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM) with an arbitrary number of outputs, and (ii) the state $|A_1(\theta)\rangle$ in the paper you referred to is *not* the orthogonal complement to $|A_0(\theta)\rangle$ and it is not the other outcome of the first measurement; instead, $|A_1(\theta)\rangle$ represents a completely different measurement Alice could do. And yes, that is confusing notation and frankly it's reprehensible that PRL let it through.)

Once you do that, then you have two possible outcomes, $|A\rangle$ and $|A^\perp \rangle$, and the probability for the former is
\begin{align}
\left\|\langle A |\Psi\rangle \right\|^2
& =
\left\|a^* x |0\rangle + b^* y |1\rangle\right\|^2
\\ & = |a^*x|^2 + |b^*y|^2.
\end{align}
It's then a good exercise to check that this adds with the probability of getting outcome $|A^\perp\rangle$ (while also ignoring Bob's side) to give unity.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, it really helps to clear things up. Could you extend it with the case when I don't want to "ignore whatever happens on Bob's side"?

Comment: As I said, if you don't want to ignore what happens on Bob's side, you need to *specify* what happens on Bob's side, which you haven't done. For details, refer e.g. to Nielsen & Chuang's *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information*.

Comment: That's fair, and thanks for the reference. One more question: say Bob measures the second qubit using projectors $|B\rangle, |B^\perp \rangle$, while Alice uses $|A\rangle, |A^\perp \rangle$ as discussed above on the first qubit. Assuming that the measurements are simultaneous and don't affect one and other, is it possible in any way that the probability of a pair of outcomes $P(\alpha \beta)$ is zero, while $P(\alpha)$ and $P(\beta)$ are each non-zero?

Comment: Yeah, that's completely reasonable, even within classical probability.

Comment: Well, yes, but what I really mean is that how I can formally compute this in the setup similar to the one described in the linked paper around equation (5), (6)...